# visual studio 2010 : Creating new project does nothing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, configuration, project

I have visual studio 2010 professional c++ and I use window 8.1 pro.

Every time I try to create a project (any type of project), that I choose a name and a valid  location for the solution, and that I click OK, closing the "new project" window, the "new project" window appear again, as if nothing happened. nothing happen apart from just project creation wizard shown again without any message.

In addition to not being able to create new projects, I can't even debug my old projects, as I have this error : "ConfigurationGeneral" rule is missing from the project.

I really have no idea what to do and am quite upset as I'm completely stuck. I tried reinstalling visual studio c++ professional 2010 but it didn't solve my problem.

Thank you for helping me find an answer to my problem :)